# mongodb findOne with explain

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to do `findOne` with explain in mongodb?

Currently I have tried:

```
db.coll.findOne({query}).explain()
db.collection.findOne({query})._addSpecial( "$explain", 1 )
```

and both were not successful.

I do understand that I can do limit 1, but is it possible to do this without it?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because `find` returns a cursor with an explain-method, while `findOne` returns the pure document.

Comment: @Philipp thank. So as I understood there is no other way except of limit?

Comment: I wouldn't know another way, but I don't feel confident enough to claim that no way exists.

Comment: If your intention is to only return one document but you do not want to return all the results you can use [$maxScan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxScan/) as a cursor modifier. `_addSpecial( "$maxScan" , 2 )` for example forces the optimizer to give up "scanning" after the first result is returned. But anything you want "explain" output from must be a cursor. Same applies, need a cursor then use `.find()`

Comment: @NeilLunn did not know about maxScan. Thank you.

Comment: findOne is just a find with limit one and pretty print option. why are you trying to avoid limit?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I know that. I just wanted to find out whether there is another option. And I learned about $maxScan.

Answer (score 0):

Explain is completely cursor method - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain

According to the documentation, you cannot apply cursor methods to findOne - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#the-findone-result-document