# Mongodb, find last record, does the total count affect the performance?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection only `insert` and `find last record` will be issued against it.

And the count of records of this collection is very big, will this affect the time of `find last record`? Or maybe the affect is negligible?

the query used to find last record:

`db.col.find().sort({created: -1}).limit(1)`

Comment: The query `db.col.find().sort({created: -1})` wont return the last record BUT all the documents in the collection in descending order. If you want to find the last record then use `findOne` instead: `db.col.findOne().sort({created: -1})`

Comment: Yes, is the time of this query a constant despite the amount of the total documents?

Comment: Use the [**`explain`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) method to get the execution stats.

Comment: More details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851335/mongodb-findone-with-explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one work

```
db.collection.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```